# Using an IP address parameter in the creation of a Socket.io socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

In the following snippet, a tutorial author shows how to alter the original tutorial to include an http server. Here's the snippet.

```
var http = require(‘http’),  
fs = require(‘fs’),  
io = require(‘socket.io’),  
index;  
fs.readFile(‘./chat.html’, function (err, data) {  
 if (err) {
    throw err;
 }
 index = data;
});
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
  response.writeHeader(200, {“Content-Type”: “text/html”});
  response.write(index);
  response.end();
}).listen(1223);
//and replace var socket = io.listen(1223, "1.2.3.4"); with:
var socket = io.listen(server);
```

The code in the original tutorial didn't include the http server, and `socket` was defined as simply:

`var socket = io.listen(1223, "1.2.3.4");`

I noticed that he replaces the variable's content `io.listen(1223, "1.2.3.4");` with `server` which doesn't include the ip (`1.2.3.4`) anywhere.

My Question:

- What is the purpose/effect of the referenced IP address?
- Why is it excluded when passing an http server to create the socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are listening on a port, you can optionally include the IP address of a specific interface to listen on.  For example, you might have several network interfaces with several IP addresses, and only want your service running on one of them.  A more common use case is that you only want your server accessible on localhost, so you might have it listen only on `127.0.0.1`.

Now, when you call `io.listen(server)` where `server` is an existing Node.js HTTP server, Socket.IO isn't actually opening a new listening connection at all.  This is a shortcut for Socket.IO to wrap its methods on the existing HTTP server.  If you wanted to specify a specific interface address to listen on, you would need to do it where `.listen()` is called on the HTTP server, above where you call `io.listen(server)`.

More info in the documentation for raw network sockets in Node.js:  http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback